# Extract Business Card data and directly save to firebase

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I want to extract name, email, phone number, and address from business card. The data is getting extracted the image preview and all text are shown in cardview but I want to extract specific fields name, email, phone and address and directly save these data to firebase storage not in preview, how to do that and where in my code I need to make changes.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;
//import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
//import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity  {
    FloatingActionButton fab_icon;
    TextView mResultEt;
    ImageView mPreviewIv;
    CardView cV;

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private static final int STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 400;
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE =1001;

    String[] cameraPermission;
    String[] storagePermission;
    Uri image_uri;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();

        mResultEt = findViewById(R.id.resultEt);
        mPreviewIv = findViewById(R.id.imageIv);
        cV= findViewById(R.id.cV);

        cameraPermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        storagePermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.menu_dash:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.menu_create:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateActivity.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.menu_card:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CardActivity.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.menu_fav:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FavActivity.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        fab_icon=findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab_icon.setOnClickListener(v -> showImageImportDialog());
    }


    private void showImageImportDialog() {
        String[] items = {"Camera", "Gallery"};
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Select Image");
        dialog.setItems(items, (dialog1, which) -> {
            if (which == 0){
                if(!checkCameraPermission()){
                    requestCameraPermission();
                }else{
                    pickCamera();
                }
            } if(which == 1){
                if(!checkStoragePermission()){
                    requestStoragePermission();
                }else{
                    pickGallery();
                }
            }

        });
        dialog.create().show();
    }

    private void pickGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE);
    }

    private void pickCamera() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "NewPic");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image to Text");
        image_uri=getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        //image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);
    }

    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, storagePermission, STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    private boolean checkStoragePermission() {
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result;
    }

    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, cameraPermission, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private boolean checkCameraPermission() {
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        boolean result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result && result1;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        switch(requestCode){
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length>0){
                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean writeStorageAccepted = grantResults[0] ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (cameraAccepted && writeStorageAccepted){
                        pickCamera();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length>0){
                    boolean writeStorageAccepted = grantResults[0] ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (writeStorageAccepted){
                        pickGallery();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE){
                assert data != null;
                CropImage.activity(data.getData())
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .start(this);
            }
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE){
                CropImage.activity(image_uri)
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .start(this);

            }
        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                assert result != null;
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                mPreviewIv.setImageURI(resultUri);
               // Intent intentGallery = new Intent(Home.this, CreateActivity.class);
                //intentGallery.putExtra("imageUri", resultUri.toString());
                //startActivity(intentGallery);

                //get drawbable bitmap for text recognition
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)mPreviewIv.getDrawable();

                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                //Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
                TextRecognizer recognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

                if (!recognizer.isOperational()){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
                    SparseArray<TextBlock> items = recognizer.detect(frame);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i<items.size(); i++){
                        TextBlock myItem = items.valueAt(i);
                        sb.append(myItem.getValue());
                        sb.append("\n");
                    }
                    mResultEt.setText(sb.toString());
                }

            }else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE){
                assert result != null;
                Exception error = result.getError();
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve that?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).